# Azure app service hosting 'Unexpected End of File'

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm

I have an App Service hosted on Microsoft Azure. After some recent code changes I started being unable to deploy the app to Azure. More specifically I started getting the following response:

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
Handling node.js deployment.
Creating app_offline.htm
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'package-lock.json'
Deleting app_offline.htm
Using start-up script server.js from package.json.
Generated web.config.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.10.3, 6.11.1, 6.11.2, 6.11.5, 6.12.2, 6.12.3, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.4.0, 8.5.0, 8.7.0, 8.8.0, 8.8.1, 8.9.0, 8.9.3, 8.9.4, 8.10.0, 8.11.1, 8.17.0, 10.0.0, 10.6.0, 10.14.1, 10.15.2, 10.16.3, 10.19.0, 12.13.0, 12.15.0, 12.18.0, 12.21.0, 14.10.1, 14.15.0, 14.15.1, 14.16.0, 14.18.1, 14.20.0, 16.9.1, 16.13.0, 16.16.0, 18.3.0, 18.12.1.
Selected node.js version 10.19.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 6.13.4
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.19.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install \\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Windows\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)

> circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall \\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\circular-json
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
> echo ''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)

''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\circular-json'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
added 185 packages from 102 contributors, removed 270 packages, updated 383 packages and audited 1451 packages in 1068.556s
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 (node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install: `node install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1


1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 275 vulnerabilities (13 low, 87 moderate, 138 high, 37 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.19.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> geek-talent-insights-app@0.0.0 build \\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot
> ng build "--prod" "--configuration" "dev" "--buildOptimizer=false"
'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot'

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Unknown error: Error: Unexpected end of file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file D:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! geek-talent-insights-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build "--prod" "--configuration" "dev" "--buildOptimizer=false"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the geek-talent-insights-app@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-10T11_20_45_505Z-debug.log
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm build failed
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!\r\nnpm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.\r\nnpm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.19.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.\r\n'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt'\r\nCMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.\r\nUNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.\r\ninternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583\r\n    throw err;\r\n    ^\r\n\r\nError: Cannot find module 'D:\Windows\install.js'\r\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)\r\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)\r\n    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)\r\n    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)\r\n    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)\r\n'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot\node_modules\circular-json'\r\nCMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.\r\nUNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.\r\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):\r\nnpm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})\r\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 (node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt):\r\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install: `node install.js`\r\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1\r\n\r\nnpm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.19.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.\r\n'\\13.93.111.102\volume-23-default\dbd2013efe0f898547bf\4025c8f8e3624c69920fb4b62f7793b6\site\wwwroot'\r\nCMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.\r\nUNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.\r\nUnknown error: Error: Unexpected end of file.\r\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\r\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\r\nnpm ERR! file D:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe\r\nnpm ERR! errno ENOENT\r\nnpm ERR! geek-talent-insights-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build "--prod" "--configuration" "dev" "--buildOptimizer=false"`\r\nnpm ERR! spawn ENOENT\r\nnpm ERR! \r\nnpm ERR! Failed at the geek-talent-insights-app@0.0.0 build script.\r\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\r\nnpm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-10T11_20_45_505Z-debug.log\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\99.50201.6113\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd bash deploy.sh
```

Now what it says is `Unknown error: Error: Unexpected end of file.` So naturally I assumed that the latest code changes caused a problem. In that vein here is what I have tried and not gotten any change to the error message:

1. Reverted the code via git to the last version able to deploy successfully.
2. deleted package-lock and node_modules and run `npm install`
3. Created a completely new azure deployment slot and connected the git branch.

None of those made any difference to the error message and the deployment failure.
I also investigated where the error message told me to go for the full log of the error but it was very much just what was shared in the message.

Basically I just need to know how to find out which file exactly is giving the `unexpected end of file` error because I can do a full `ng build --prod` locally with no issues whatsoever.

---

It was mentioned there might be something wrong with `angular.json`. I have given it a quick review and it seems to be okay, but I've attached it here. Maybe someone else can see something I can't:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "geek-talent-insights-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/spinkit/css/spinners/3-wave.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "geek-talent-insights-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "geek-talent-insights-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "geek-talent-insights-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "scripts": [],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/spinkit/css/spinners/3-wave.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "geek-talent-insights-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "geek-talent-insights-app:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "geek-talent-insights-app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if there is anything wrong in "angular.json"

Comment: @dLcreations It seems to be okay, but I've included it in the question if it helps.